# Is there a geo-fence map of Apple's or Google's reverse geocoding?

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, maps, apple

Is there a map that shows how lat/long maps to locality/county/sublocality/subadmin and possibly covered area?

Answer (score 2):

No, each lat/lng is done individually to match an address. (Using Google)

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding

> Note: Reverse geocoding is an estimate. The geocoder will attempt to
>   find the closest addressable location within a certain tolerance; if
>   no match is found, the geocoder will return zero results.

I don't use Apple products so cannot comment on Apple Maps (they do need to improve a lot).

**Nokia (they own Navteq) and MapQuest** are also a good contenders for reverse geocoding

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Nokia_Maps_API_-_Using_the_geocoding_service

http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/nominatim

Comment: I am not looking for a reverse geocoding service but an overall map of where lat/lng falls in place and how that map defines its geo-fences at each scale. Even approximately.

Comment: It does not exist as far as I know, been using gmaps since beta, it is based on algorithms and would be classified as 'commercially sensitive' as they do not want competitors to have that knowledge.

Comment: Or in other words, it's not really standardised across providers.

Comment: "[Trade secrets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trade_secrets)".

Answer (score 0):

Tiger Census 5-Digit ZIP Code Tabulation Areas (ZCTAs)
Cartographic Boundary Files is where you want to go.
If you want to pay and have a much higher accuracy rate use Maponics or Navteq data